# Is it possible to query LDAP for extended Active Directory properties?

Tags: active-directory

I am attempting to build an application that lists all of the accounts that are currently locked in Active Directory. As far as I understand it, Active Directory changes the `LockedOut` property of the object to `true` when an account is locked, and that relying on other methods is not too reliable, such as seeing if `lockoutTime>1`.

I know you can see this property, and more, if you run `get-aduser johndoe -properties *` but I have not been able to get all of the properties via LDAP queries.

In other words, is it possible to pull extended AD properties such as `lockedOut` via an LDAP query?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous answer was indeed wrong. However, after doing some research it seems that:

1. The `lockoutTime` attribute being unset or 0 reliably indicates that the account is **not** locked out. (See the remarks section of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
2. The `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed` bit-field attribute reliably indicates whether the account is locked (in case the `0x10` bit is set), but it being a computed value cannot be included in a search filter.

So the best solution might be to query for all accounts that **may** be locked with a filter like `(&(objectClass=user)(lockoutTime>=1))`, and then programmatically filter the results further by inspecting the `0x10` bit of the `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed` attribute, so that you have accurate results.

The same solution is outlined at the end of [this article](http://www.selfadsi.org/extended-ad/search-locked-users.htm).

Comment: btw you'll need to use SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry() to get the DirectoryEntry object. Then use $directoryEntry.Properties["msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed"] to get the value.